# Can a turbine mechanism work to generate energy from a lightsaber/beam saber?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology, energy

The turbine mechanism is surrounding a [lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber/Legends) or [beamsaber](https://gundambattleoperation.fandom.com/wiki/Beam_Saber) like a sheath or scabbard on a sword, or like a cylinder tube. The turbine is inside the sheath and looks like a blade ring facing the lightsaber/beamsaber inside. It acts as a portable generator to generate energy from the heat while cooling the outer surface so a human can safely grasp it.

The turbine material is not lightsaber/beamsaber resistant so upon/prolonged direct contact it can melt the turbine material so there will be some gap between the lightsaber/beamsaber which is positioned in the middle or works as a core, the generator is made entirely of this material so no other materials in this.

Also please don't take it too literally as a lightsaber/beamsaber which is made of plasma/laser, but just assume it is a heat generating sword (it does have weak radiation though).

Can this work to get energy from a lightsaber/beamsaber? Feel free to suggest better methods or systems while still cooling the outer surface, outside of changing the material, I am not really knowledgeable about this stuff.

Comment: I tried my best, but I have no idea what you are talking about. Do we assume the lightsaber just works as is? Do you want to gather the heat (infrared?) radiation emitted by the blade?

Comment: @openend what you mean with lightsaber work as is? you mean it can generate heat indefinitely? yeah either by radiation or convection.

Comment: If you mean, can you use a Lightsaber as a heat source to boil water for use in a turbine power generator... then yes? Surely you could find an easier way to get the power from the Lightsaber's battery directly though. 

If you are counting on powering the turbine with air from the atmosphere directly, then again yes it could be done, but would be quite inefficient.

Comment: @abestrange through air, but since it reverse i want to confirm it, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can power the lightsabre by collecting the heat energy it emits itself? If so, the answer is no. That would be a perpetual motion machine, and they cannot exist because there are always losses.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII no its to power another machine such as power armor.

Comment: Why not take the battery out of the lightsaber and use it to power your turbine directly.... those things didn't run on pure magic.

Comment: @Shadowzee well the lightsaber not generate from any battery but from chemical or unique material reaction of the lightsaber itself,  embeded/blended/merges with the lightsaber, stuff like that, just dont take the literal lightsaber that using crystal or battery to empower it.

Comment: So the lightsabre already has a magical infinite power source?

Comment: @ArkensteinXII yeah i guess, but merge with the lightsaber material, and i think it require oxygen to generate it though.

Comment: If the lightsabre already functions via impossible physics, then the only answer to your question is: "Sure! Why not?" However, if you possess the techno-magic to power a lightsabre this way, why not incorporate the same thing into the power armour and skip the turbine step?

Comment: If you have an infinite source of heat, you should be able to create a turbine or Engine. However the specifics of such a design would require years of training, especially if the entire turbine is made out of the exact material. The energy source will melt the turbine and it needs to be small enough to be hand held. Are you looking for a design, or a mechanism that makes the turbine work? or a reality check if the idea work? You ask "Can this work" like a reality check, but have tagged it as science-based.

Comment: Use the Force to directly power whatever device you wanted the energy for. Search your feelings, you know it to be true.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII well as i say it merge with the lightsaber material that generate heat or create lightsaber, and i dont want the power armor to generate ligthsaber or heat because it seems dangerous for the body itself.

Comment: @Shadowzee well yeah i want to confirm can it work but i also want to know is there other design that work better if there exist (outide of the battery one mention here.

Comment: @LiJun - There is almost no reason why a dangerous external lightsaber is a better mechanism for a power source than an internal, contained mechanism leveraging the same power source.

Comment: @jdunlop i want to make it have versatility as weapon and energy generator rather than just for the armor, beside the material for the light saber itself is rare in my world something like legendary artifact unknown by the people to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should be possible. Most engines and turbines work by using Heat to expand a material like Air, Oil or Water and then using this material to push a turbine or piston.

The most basic versions of this are simply a tall standing tube painted black, with a little fan place on the top. With some basic sunshine, the black tube absorbs the heat, warms the air which moves up and spins the fan.

A similar concept would be the Fusion core from the Fall out game series. However what you have fundamentally described is a Turbine Engine. The biggest difference however is that you have replaced  the core of the turbine with your energy source, so instead of having fuel gushing in, compressing and exploding, you have a single piece of plasma that will eventually melt your engine down.

So the plasma super heats air, the air expands and pushes a turbine. Now as the turbine spins, it will help pull in more air, which the plasma then heats and so on in a cycle. This cycle will reach an equilibrium, where the air being pulled into the engine isn't expanding enough to power the turbine, so it isn't going to just get faster and faster and faster forever. The max speed is going to depend on how much air your plasma can heat up and how hot it will get.

The best part of this, is that by pulling in all this air, it will naturally cool parts of your engine for you, however it is always going to be shooting out a stream of hot and fast air which you don't really want anyone to be standing in. You can search up videos of a guy who has made a prototype flying suit and he just has miniature turbine engines attached to his arms, back and legs, so the engine itself is definitely hold-able and naturally cool-able e.g. For some NASA rockets, the fuel line wraps around the combustion area cooling the materials and helping to heat up the fuel for ignition. In your case, the air would do this.

The biggest issue your going to face is starting off the turbine engine. It will take time to build up the necessary air flow, and during this time, there is a very high chance your infinite source of heat and power (plasma) will melt the engine down. You might need to kick start every engine created with a huge flow of air to ensure your infinite sources of energy don't break down the moment they are made. In addition to this, it will need to constantly draw in a very high volume of air which can become problematic if your inlets get blocked. However materials like liquids and solids can still parse through your turbine, it might however damage it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, why not? Most beam-sword type weapons in fiction appear to use intense heat as their main method of operation, so there's no reason that heat couldn't be used to boil steam and spin a turbine.

There are reasons this might be a silly. It seems a bit weird that your society has enough exposure to and free time with these beam swords that they can build a turbine around them, but for whatever reason aren't able to tap into the beam sword power source directly. But that's not physics or anything.